# In Xcode is there a way to show only certain symbols in the symbols navigator (cmd-2)?

Tags: xcode, symbols

I used the symbols navigator(cmd - 2) in xCode extensively between different methods and properties in my classes. I then put an extension on one of my classes. The symbol navigator now shows the methods and properties not in the extension and a drop down menu for the all the methods and properties in the extension. The problem is this includes every methods and property in the extension of the class which is so many more than just the ones I have added myself (e.g ones cocoa has). There's probably 400 so I lose the quick navigation ability I had. I was wondering if there is anyway to get around this problem and only show the extension properties and methods I had written myself?

I can't include a link because I am new to the site but here is what happens when I click on the drop down menu. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEMvT.jpg

Comment: Use the filter bar at the bottom? Its buttons too?

Comment: The filter buttons do seem to work on methods in my classes but not on those in the extension. When I extend the extension drop down menu I get hundreds of methods that aren't mine. I will add a picture into my question to show this, thank you for responding as well.

Comment: I can't add an image because I only just joined this site but I can include a link to http://imgur.com/a/UQF4P @matt

Comment: Please show your code. You cannot write an extension of CGFloat inside a view controller, and CGFloat has none of the properties shown in the screen shot, so something very odd is going on.

Comment: @matt https://github.com/lewisjamesblack/routeGame2 Here's my code. The extension are of the GVC which is just a viewController. I've absolutely no idea where the CGFloat bit came from which is confusing me as well but i'm really not experienced with swift & xcode so I thought it was just something I wouldn't understand.

Comment: No, I'd say you've found a legitimate bug. Xcode just doesn't understand the way you've split this code over multiple files, I guess. I'd send this in as a bug report to Apple if I were you.